# How can I find number of links on a webpage pointing to same domain name as of webpage using python , beautifulsoup?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I was trying to get all the links using BeautifulSoup and comparing to the domain name like example.com. Can anyone help in this regard?

Comment: Show us what you have tried already. See [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, here is the python code for it :

```
import urllib.request as Ureq
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from urllib.parse import urlparse
def task(url):
    x=Ureq.urlopen(url)
    print ("Total Size of the Web Page = ",len(x.read())," Bytes")
    url_p=urlparse(url)
    domain='{uri.scheme}://{uri.netloc}/'.format(uri=url_p)
    print (domain)
    resp=requests.get(url)
    soup=bs(resp.text,'html.parser')
    r=0
    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        temp=link.get('href')
        if temp is not None and domain in temp:
        print (temp)
        r=r+1
    print ("Total links pointing to same domain = ",r)
URl_User="abc"
URL_User=input('Enter URl : ')
task(URL_User)
```